# Rewrite Condition not working for Rewrite rule on individual pages

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I am trying to write a rule that will capture any url that does NOT have sales/anything up to a .php or .php3 file and anything after that - if there is anything - and rewrite that to a new website as per below:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/sales/.*php3?).*
RewriteRule ^/sales/([^./]*)$ http://www2.domain.com/sales$1/index.shtml [R,L]
```

It captures if I put in www.domain.com/sales but if I put in just http://www.domain.com/sales/trucks.shtml if does not capture the individual pages.

Can anyone see what I need to do to get this to work correctly please ?

**To clarify:**

.If I put in url www.domain.com/sales, the site redirects to www2.domain.com/sales/index.shtml ....however if I put in the url www.domain.com/sales/trucks.shtml the condition is not picked up and the url does not rewrite to the ww2 site so I am stuck on the old page still ....thanks for your help

Comment: Better to provide some examples. e.g. what is target URL for `http://www.domain.com/sales/trucks.shtml`?

Comment: Sorry ..If I put in url www.domain.com/sales, the site redirects to www2.domain.com/sales/index.shtml ....however if I put in the url www.domain.com/sales/trucks.shtml the condition is not picked up and the url does not rewrite to the ww2 site so I am stuck on the old page still ....thanks for your help

Comment: Following same logic should `http://www.domain.com/sales/trucks.shtml` be rewritten as `http://www.domain2.com/sales/trucks.shtml/index.shtml`?

Comment: No...if you put in http://www.domain.com/sales/trucks.shtml it should go to http://www2.domain.com/sales/trucks.shtml .... so just the Domain should change ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright use these 2 rules for your requirements:

```
RewriteRule ^sales/?$ http://www2.domain.com/sales/index.shtml [R,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^sales/(?!.*\.php3?$).*$ http://www2.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L,NC]
```